# Is it thread safe to use WriteAsync on NetworkStream from multyple threads at same time?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

When having a `TcpClient` taking its `stream` in multiple threads and performing `WriteAsync` into it on each thread. Is it thread safe? Will data (byte arrays passed to write method) be delivered as intact chuncs passed to `WriteAsync`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not safe.

From the [MSDN under Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xae4f4.aspx):

> Read and write operations can be performed simultaneously on an
>   instance of the NetworkStream class without the need for
>   synchronization. As long as there is one unique thread for the write
>   operations and one unique thread for the read operations, there will
>   be no cross-interference between read and write threads and no
>   synchronization is required.

So when you have multiple writing threads you need to synchronize these.

Comment: BTW does WriteAsync block? So if I'll put it into ` lock (stream)
                { stream.WriteAsync(...); }` so that only one thread would write at a time would it be possible not to lock read operations  that would be performed by seprate thread (1 thread)?

Comment: I think you'll be in danger of writing and reading at the same time this way.

Comment: What about writing zero bytes to check the connection?

Comment: @MohammadNikravan - I am not aware if this would give any useful information about the connection. Writing zero bytes might update the state of the TcpClient and thus might interfere with other threads.